# Can beasts benefit from magic items?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, monsters, animals

Can a non-player beast benefit from a magic item's effects? For example, would a cat that was wearing a headband of intellect get the extra intelligence the item gives?

Comment: Related: [Can a familiar attune and wear or use a magic item?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107328/can-a-familiar-attune-and-wear-or-use-a-magic-item), [Can an animal attune to a magic item?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/115569/can-an-animal-attune-to-a-magic-item)

Comment: There are currently magic items specifically made **for** beasts in 5e. *Horseshoes of Speed* are an example.

Answer (score 29):

All creatures can benefit from and use magic items subject to their anatomical limitations and other capacities.

For example, a creature without a head cannot use a *Headband of Intellect* and a creature with a head but without the knowledge and understanding of magic items (like most beasts) would not know to wear it. Of course, if someone else were to put it on their dog, say, then it would benefit *and* now have intelligence enough to work out what's going on.

Volo's Guide to Monsters specifically calls out beholders as wearing rings on their eye stalks and using wands through telekinesis.

Comment: I'm a little dubious about this example because the Headband of Intellect requires attunement, and according to the 5e SRD attunement seems to be a pretty deliberate process.  I love dogs, but I've never known one smart enough "to  spend  a  short  rest  focused  on  only  that  item  while  being  in physical  contact  with  it", especially since being focused on it "can  take  the  form  of  weapon  practice  (for  a  weapon), meditation  (for  a  wondrous  item),  or  some  other appropriate  activity".

Comment: @Percival You are probably right in some cases, but I don't think attunement is meant to be a specific, detailed process. Its more coming to know the item you are wearing/using. In the examples mentioned it makes sense you cannot use a sword well until you practice with it. But equipment simply requires wearing it and interacting it (I would expect).

Comment: If you want to really be specific and the dog example is not to your liking, awake him with the spell. After that he will definitely be a good boy and attune to it. And now I want a super intelligent awakened Shrub XD